# Building a complex predicate to compare attribute string contains any string in Array

Tags: ios, sql, objective-c, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have an `entity name A` and it has an attribute `A.uid`. Now I have an `array of Strings` containing `global UIDs`. Now any string in this array can be substring of A.uid. How to build a complex `NSPredicate` for `NSFetchReuqest` for this so that it gives me only those A objects which have this substring match from array of strings. I am assuming we can't use NSString operations inside `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:]`.

I have tried using `IN` for this but I want to somehow figure out substring approach inside my `SUBQUERY`. Also I have to make a `SUBQUERY` otherwise use of `IN` is throwing error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an Objective-C project handy, but this worked in Swift and should do the job for you (if I understand your question).

I ran this on a core data entity with a single attribute: name

```
NSArray *a = @[
    @"123",
    @"456",
];

NSString *searchString = [a componentsJoinedByString:@"|"];
NSString *format = @"(name MATCHES %@)";
NSString *pattern = [NSString stringWithFormat:@".*(%@).*", searchString];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:format, pattern];
```

My data consists of:

```
Joe123Smith
Bob456Smith
Dave789Smith
Steve764Smith
Tom12345Smith
Mike397456288Smith
123TimSmith
TomSmith456
```

and the returned matched set of records is:

```
Joe123Smith
Bob456Smith
Tom12345Smith
Mike397456288Smith
123TimSmith
TomSmith456
```

---

**Edit**

I just tested this on an Objective-C project and it works as expected.